# Object value is changed before setting it in Unreal Engine 4.27.2

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm verifying the value of a *Text* object in Unreal then setting the value after the *branch* node. However the value is changed before. I managed to isolate the issue and reproduce the bug in that small blueprint (The execution before is just the *BeginPlay* event attaching the debug interface then leading up here):
[image]

The results in the *Direction* Trace output (Small function that displays the value requested) is always "Up" and the *Actual Content* shows "New Value".

However, *Direction* will be "Down" and *Actual Content* will show the correct original value ("Hazard 3") if I remove the last node that sets "Short Difficulty Name".

Furthermore, if I compare the original value with a random integer like so:
[image]
*Direction* will show "Down" while "Actual Content" still shows "New Value"

I really don't get it, tried copying the value of the Text instead in case it was a pointer issue, reading online if the *Branch* node or pure functions had a delay, comparing *Text* instead of *String*..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the issue by adding a 0.0001s delay after reading variable and before writing anything, then the values were correct.